# Rice cooker problem: film appears after cooking

Tags: rice, rice-cooker

What is this and why does it appear?
It always happened, maybe I cook rice the wrong way, or maybe it comes from the rice itself...

[image: After cooking]

I wash the rice with water before, at least 3-4 times. I don't even cook it until it's completely done, I stop it before today in order to check if it's due to overcooked rice or not. It isn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is perfectly okay to eat. I am going to assume when you cook rice, the rice comes out a bit too moist. The "film" is literally the water and the starch from the rice that has dried and turned into a thin film of rice starch.

If you like your rice the way it currently is, then there is nothing to worry about. But if it indeed is too moist, then decrease the amount of water you use to cook the rice.